# Is there a way to call multiple APIs using just one Server Side Event Connection?

Tags: python, reactjs, server-sent-events, rest, fastapi

Our Usecase involves multiple API calls for multiple Clients. which uses a polling mechanism. We have been trying to overcome this using SSEs for each client. But is there a way to have one connection to one client and can we pass multiple API calls using that single connection rather then creating new connections for each and every api calls?

```
@app.get('/stream/{client_id}')
async def message_stream(client_id, request: Request):
    def new_messages():
        ...

    async def event_generator():
        while True:
            # If client was closed the connection
            if await request.is_disconnected():
                break
            # Checks for new messages and return them to client if any
            if new_messages():
                yield {
                    "event": "new_message",
                    "id": "message_id",
                    "retry": MESSAGE_STREAM_RETRY_TIMEOUT,
                    "data": "message_content"
                }
            await asyncio.sleep(MESSAGE_STREAM_DELAY)

    return EventSourceResponse(event_generator())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(app, host="127.0.0.1", port=8000)
```

is there a way to use `Yield` to call other API routes?

Comment: You might want to add on to your question because it's hard to understand what you're asking. `yield` is just a keyword for generators the same way `return` is a keyword for functions. `yield` itself doesn't call any APIs but there's nothing stopping you from calling other APIs and yielding their results.

Comment: My doubt was that could I pass a API URL as a string in yield["data"] from the client side and call that specific API in the backend API. if that is do-able, then I could have one single connection where I can pass multiple URLs in same connection. I couldn't figure any way of calling a API in Python in backend itself.

Comment: Then it sounds like all you need is the requests module: https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/